# Permitir que un boton se habilite o deshabilite mediante una consulta msyql

Tags: php, html, mysql, botón

Tengo la siguiente consulta de lo mas básico que se pueda realizar.

```
SELECT
      control_patrimonial.bienes.Validacion AS VALIDADO,
      FROM control_patrimonial.bienes
     WHERE control_patrimonial.bienes.numero_empleado='$numero_empleado'
```

el resultado de esta consulta puede variar entre los valores 0,1 y 2,  suponiendo que un empleado tiene 6 activos y no se le ha realizado su revisión, y el empleado por consecuencia no ha validado sus activos, entonces el resultado de la consulta debería regresar:
0
0
0
0
0
0
En cuyo caso el botón de impresión debería estar deshabilitado, ahora el siguiente escenario seria que ya fueron revisados y validados los activos, en cuyo caso el resultado de la consulta seria:

1
1
1
1
1
1
En este sentido, pues el botón de impresión debería habilitarse ya que cumple con que todos sus activos han sido validados,  pero existe otro escenario donde la posibilidad de que el usuario haya omitido o rechazado la validación de algún activo, siendo que pudiera quedar al menos la salida de esta manera
para una omisión por parte del usuario:
0
1
1
1
1
1
y cuando existe al menos un rechazo por parte del usuario:
2
1
1
1
1
1

Entonces aquí la cuestión es que si no están todos los activos en valor 1. Se debe deshabilitar el botón.

intente hacer esto:

```html
if($estadoValidacion == 1) {
                             ?>
                            <button id="btnImprimeResguardo" name="boton"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="ImprimeResguardo"  title="DESCARGAR RESGUARDO"> <img  type="button" src="imagenes/iconos/acciones/impresion.png" width="35" height="35" >&nbsp;IMPRIMIR</button>
                        <?PHP
                        } else {
                        ?>
                            <button id="btnImprimeResguardo" name="boton"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  value="ImprimeResguardo"  title="IMPRIMIR RESGUARDO" disabled="disabled" > <img  type="button" src="imagenes/iconos/acciones/impresion.png" width="35" height="35">&nbsp;IMPRIMIR</button>
                        <?PHP
                        }
```

Pero no me funciona. En otra sección del sistema con un evento muy similar lo único que se hizo fue
añadir la instrucción MIN a la consulta y regresa determinado valor que permite bloquear otros botones, pero en este caso no se ha logrado.

```
SELECT
          MIN(control_patrimonial.bienes.Validacion) AS VALIDADO,
          FROM control_patrimonial.bienes
         WHERE control_patrimonial.bienes.numero_empleado='$numero_empleado'
```

Siempre me va a regresar un valor que por lo general sera el mas pequeño, pero en esta situación tan solo me estaría validando cuando tenga algún 0, y no cuando tenga un 2.

En cuyo caso si modifico la consulta de esta manera :

```
SELECT
      MAX(control_patrimonial.bienes.Validacion) AS VALIDADO,
      FROM control_patrimonial.bienes
     WHERE control_patrimonial.bienes.numero_empleado='$numero_empleado'
```

Pues ahora me regresara el valor mas alto, en cuyo caso si encontrara la siguiente secuencia
000001, tendría el 1, y por consiguiente habilitaría el botón, que no debería ser valido ya que se requiere que todos los activos tengan 1.  Y en el supuesto que tuviera
000002 o 111112 pues en este caso se supondría que me bloquea el botón al corresponder con el valor mas alto, pero no lo haría si tuviera 000000.  Y pues de esta manera no cumple con la validación que se pretende.

Pensé que podría hacerlo de otra manera, que en lugar de evaluar la variable que sea igual a 1, que deshabilite el botón cuando sea diferente de 1,  pero el problema seguirá siendo la consulta, ya que no encuentro como traer el valor mas representativo.

Mientras sigo pensando como hacerle.

Se agradece cualquier aportación.

Saludos

Comment: Si de lo que se trata es de verificar si todas las filas tienen el valor `1` puedes hacer algo así: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTabla WHERE laColumna != 1;`  Si esa consulta te trae un valor igual a `0` signfica que todas las filas de `laColumna` tienen valor igual a `1`;  por el contrario si trae un resultado mayor a `1` significa que hay al menos una fila en la que `laColumna` no tiene el estado `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes manejar como una operación a nivel de bits:

```
SELECT bit_and(b.Validacion=1) VALIDADO
  FROM control_patrimonial.bienes b
  WHERE b.numero_empleado='$numero_empleado'
```

`bit_and()` también es una función de agregación como `min()` y `max()`.
Un AND sólo es verdadero (`1`) cuando sus operandos son verdaderos.

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, modifique un poco la consulta, el resultado es el mismo, si cumple la condición un 1, en cualquier otra circunstancia es 0, entonces el botón se bloquea sin mas.  Excelente aportación.  Gracias!!!  Saludos